# SOAPClient returns Parsing WSDL error Couldn't load from 'https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1?

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soap-client

I am trying to make client request using SOAPclient and this is mycode

```
 $opts = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'ciphers' => 'RC4-SHA',
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ),
            );

            // SOAP 1.2 client
            $params = array(
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'verifypeer' => false,
                'verifyhost' => false,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'connection_timeout' => 180,
                'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
            );

$config->url = 'https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1';
$soapClient = new SoapClient($config->url, $params);
```

but this returns me error

```
{"exception":"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1' : failed to load external entity \"https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1\"\n"}
```

Now I am supposing I am missing something as I have same request on postman and on that I am getting proper response because I have set headers also and I am assuming that this error is caused by missing headers or something like that

[image: POSTMAN request response]

What I am missing on my soapClient request

Answer (score 0):

In your URL you forgot WSDL at end

```
try {
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'),
        'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'RC4-SHA',
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            ),
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $wsdlUrl = 'https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1.wsdl';
    $soapClientOptions = array(
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);

    $checkVatParameters = array(
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'verifypeer' => false,
        'verifyhost' => false,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => 1,
        'connection_timeout' => 180,
    );

    $result = $client->checkVat($checkVatParameters);
    print_r($result);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Sometimes the problem can be that some versions of php, the SoapClient does not send http user agent information.

Try to set the user agent explicitly, using the example above.

Comment: i tried nothing happened  {"exception":"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1?WSDL' : failed to load external entity \"https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/DomesticPayService1?WSDL\"\n"}" ...... see the error

Comment: try the above example